# Editing all instances of a string in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have several instances of a variable or a phrase, and I want to rename it.  How do I edit all of them at the same time in Notepad++?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

CTRL+H to get to the Replace dialog (or Search ==> Replace via the menu).

Input the string to find and input the string to replace it with and then hit the 'replace all' button on the right.

Comment: is there no way notepad automatically knows which other var names to rename? I just want to rename a variable inside a function but outside of it there are plenty other vars with the same name. I'm looking for something like the ctrl-r function in netbeans.

Comment: The question is about editing all instances, the answer is search/replace, which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use Notepad++'s Mutli-Editing feature to do this inline.

https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/editing/#multi-editing

Comment: This requres manually selecting instances. How can ALL instances be selected automatically?